# how to check monogdb database connection

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, logging, database

Working with Node.js(monogdb, express and other modules)
I'm wondering if there is a mongoose method for database connection, something like if I open a connection `var db = mongoose.connect('mongo://localhost/members');` then I can `db.on('close', function(){ /*do stuffs here*/})`.

Basicly, the function below does the job of getting a user list from database and logging when database connection is closed.

So I need something in the `if()` to check database connection or whatever just unable to get data while its off and make a logging. I tried `if(docs != null)` it seems just off tho. Any advice would be much appreciated!

```
var logger = require('bunyan');

var log = new logger({
name: "loggings",
streams: [  
    {
        level: 'error',
        path: 'test.log',   
    }
],
serializers: {
    err: logger.stdSerializers.err,
}

});

function(req, res){
memberModel.find(function(err, docs){
    if (/*connection is closed*/) {
        res.render('users.jade', { members: docs });    
    }else{
            try {
                throw new DatabaseError ("Error!");
            } catch (err){
                log.warn({err: err}, "Check database connection!");
            }
        res.render('index.jade');
    };
});
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you checking in the place you are for the database connection being closed?  If it is closed at that point, then it is likely that docs will be null.  I think checking

```
if (!err) {
   res.render('users.jade', { members : docs });
} else { 
    /* throw err, etc */
```

is a reasonable course to take.

Since you want to log when the database connection is closed, why not attach a logging function to the Db's "close" event?

If I've misunderstood and checking for the connection's state is what you really want, then I'd recommend playing around with the properties of:

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#connection_Connection

(hit the "show code" button).  The connection's _closeCalled property looks like it may be what you want to check.

Answer (score 0):

You can use mongoose events that will get fire whenever your server get disconnected:

```
mongoose.connection.on('error', function (err) {
    console.log('Mongoose default connection error: ' + err);
   //HERE SERVE YOUR DISCONNECT WARNING PAGE AND LOGGER
});

mongoose.connection.on('disconnected', function () {
    console.log('Mongoose default connection disconnected');
   //HERE SERVE YOUR DISCONNECT WARNING PAGE AND LOGGER

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var uri = 'mongodb://localhost/user1';
var promise = mongooose.connect(uri,{
    useMongoClient: true,
    });

promise.openUri(uri,function(errr,db){
    if(errr){
        throw errr;
    }else{
        console.log("Connection Successfull");                  
        glo_db = db;
    }
});
```

> Above could needs to be written for the newer version of mongoose and would throw error if any error is found while connecting to a database.
>   [Check here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html)